# How setup local reporsitory for nodejs npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

As I understand node js building process you should call the following goals:

1. call `npm install` which create folder `node_modules` and put all dependencies from `package.json` into it.
2. [for UI development] run some goal which moves all files (including `node_modules`) to `dist` folder.
3. run something like `node appFile.js`

I came to node js development from Maven world which has similar dependency concept, but it does not "install" all dependencies into the project folder. It put them into local repository first and move to project `target` (`dist` analog) folder only when you invoke `package` goal. Why it is better:

1. All projects can share same files in one folder. E.g. it is not necessary to copy the same dependency to project folder every time. Just when you need to package (build) project
2. You do not need to download dependencies every time, just copy from `local repository` folder.
3. IDE does not need to update dozen `*_folders` so development process is much faster.

So the question is - Does node js support organizing the project in a similar way to avoid dozen `node_modules` creating for each project?

Comment: Could you pleease comment why downvote? I do not know much about nodejs.

Comment: Might be because of the Java tag.

Comment: In Maven world you have the same concept which is called the local cache..in a CI environment you should do the same having a local cache for each job. It does not matter if Maven or nodejs...

Comment: the title misleads people who see it in search results. i don't quite get what the question actually is so I'll just flag this.

Answer (score 1):

## First

> Does nodejs support to orginize project in similar way to avoid dozen node_modules creating for each project?

It is supported.

The answer you are searching is the **'-g'** on **npm install**

Example:

```
npm install -g lodash
```

Will create the node module globally and allow your node application to find this module without installing it at your root folder

But let me warn you, if the package system exists it is because of the versioning problems. Sometimes for differents projects application you need to have different package versions and with the -g you can't

## Second

> 2. [for ui development] run some goal wich move all files (including node_modules) to dist fodler.

It is not literally 'moving', this process you are describing is usually automated scripts like 'gulp' or even 'grunt' which allow your project to be modified in different ways.

1. Usually, it is used for

   - uglify (/dev/myscript.js become /dist/myscript.min.js),
   - concat,
   - filter
   - jshint
     and many mores.

Comment: The `npm install -g` might cause problem cause within a CI environment this might not be allowed.